# Sort List using buttons from Toolbar Menu

Tags: java, sorting, menu

I want to Sort my `listiview` using buttons from toolbar menu. I have `db.fetchByDate()`, `db.fetchByName()` and `db.fetchByAge()` which use ORDER BY in Database to display data by Date, Name and Age respectively.

I have an if-else condition to sort the list according to user choice. The problem is how can I check which of the three sorting option is selected. What should be a reliable solution to add at `//Do something here`.

My Main Activity is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseAdapter db;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    db = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    db.open();


    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    int ls = R.layout.list_item;
    int[] xml_id = new int[] {
            R.id.txtname,
            R.id.txtage
    };
    String[] column = new String[] {
            "name",
            "age"
    };

    //If-else condition to check which user option is selected

    if(){
    Cursor row = db.fetchByDate();
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, ls,row,column, xml_id, 0);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }else if(){
    Cursor row = db.fetchByName();
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, ls,row,column, xml_id, 0);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }else if(){
    Cursor row = db.fetchByAge();
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, ls,row,column, xml_id, 0);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


    //onClick function
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View view, int position, long id) {
            Cursor row = (Cursor) av.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String _id = row.getString(row.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
            String name = row.getString(row.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
            String age = row.getString(row.getColumnIndexOrThrow("age"));


            Intent details = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Details.class);
            details.putExtra("ID",_id);
            details.putExtra("NAME", name);
            details.putExtra("AGE",age);

            finish();
            startActivity(details);
        }
    });

}

// Toolbar menu that contains three sorting options

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //Sort by Date

    if (id == R.id.action_sortDate) {
        //Do something here
    }
    //Sort by Name

    if (id == R.id.action_sortName) {
        //Do something here
    }
    //Sort by Age

    if (id == R.id.action_sortAge) {
        //Do something here
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `onCreate` code will not be executed after you select the menu items. So you could create the adapter on the menu item clicked.

Comment: Or if you want to persist across the application execution, you can use `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: @thyago stall Ok. I will create an adapter. Thanks